# NSBundle finds mp3 file but not m4a when trying to instantiate AVAudioPlayer

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, ios6.1

I have a simple app that is supposed to play a audio file. Whenever I load a mp3 file to my NSURL is works fine and the AVAudioPlayer gets to play the song. However, when I change to a m4a file, the NSString path returns nil, like it is not able to find the path to my file, and thus the NSURL is not formed. The m4a file is of course there, in the project. It follows below the code, but I don't think is a code issue. Any ideias? Thanks.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"end" ofType:@"m4a"];
NSURL *urlFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSError *error;
soundPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:urlFile error:&error];
if (error)
{
    NSLog(@"Error in audioPlayer: %@",[error localizedDescription]);
} else {
    soundPlayer.delegate = self;
    [soundPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [soundPlayer play];
}
```

Comment: Did you check that the file has been added to the target?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check your Target's Build Phases, if your m4a file is not listed under Copy Bundle Resources phase group, add it, then Clean, and Run again.

Comment: Thanks Yazid this worked. Any idea of why the mp3 went to the Bundle Resources and the m4a did not?

Comment: @user1612579 When you drag files into your project, there's a window that pops up with some options. You just need to make sure to tick the option which adds the file to your target. You may have missed it out.

Comment: Huh, mp3 has the tick set for your target when you import, m4a don't!!